# Remove all initial numbers from string until non-numerical character is reached

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to remove the first numbers of a string of characters (remove all numbers until first non-numerical character is reached). Some strings have starting numbers formatted in the form of `"14 214"` where it should read `14214`. This is the special space for separating numbers, and if the string in A1 starts by `14 214` then

```
ISNUMBER(LEFT(A1,3)*1)=TRUE
```

So that means that the space is not a problem, I just have to check for the first non-numerical character.

I thought of the following VBA function:

```
Function RemoveNumbers(Txt As String) As String

i = 1
Do While i < 9
    If (IsError(Left(Txt, i) * 1)) = "False" Then
    i = i + 1
Else
    RemoveNumbers = Right(Txt, Len(Txt) - i)
End If
Loop
End Function
```

But it returns #VALUE!

Is the function correctly written? Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I would look into `Range.Characters` and `CHR()`.

Answer (score 1):

Walk along the string from left to right, looking at each character.

If the char is a space do nothing, if its a number replace it with a space otherwise return the string with leading spaces removed:

```
Function RemoveNumbers(txt As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        Select Case Mid$(txt, i, 1)
            Case " ":
            Case "0" To "9": Mid$(txt, i, 1) = " "
            Case Else
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
    RemoveNumbers = LTrim$(txt)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution from Alex K.

I would just like to add that the basic problem with the original program was that iserror does *not* catch the number conversion error - as soon as that occurs the whole function exits and you just get a value error because RemoveNumbers is not set. Also the error doesn't occur when you have left(txt,i)="14 ", but only on the next character when you have left(txt,i)="14 2". To make it work you would have to do something like this

```
Function RemoveNumbers(Txt As String) As String

On Error GoTo Handler

i = 1

Do While i <= Len(Txt)
    firstNumber = Left(Txt, i) * 1
    i = i + 1
Loop

Handler: 
    RemoveNumbers = Right(Txt, Len(Txt) - i + 1)    
End Function
```